# ¿Cómo hacer un "Come vocales" utilizando for y condicionales?

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones, else

quería consultarles como hacer un come vocales con las herramientas básicas de un curso de Python para no programadores.   No puedo usar herramientas avanzadas, solo el for, while y los condicionales.  Sé que el ejercicio tiene solución, pero estoy trabado hace dos días.

Pongo este código como ejemplo, ya probé varias opciones:

```
ing_pal = input("Ingresa una palabra.\n De lo contrario me comeré la vocal!")

for letra in ing_pal:
    if letra != ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
        print(letra)
    else:
        print(letra, " ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo es comparar que cada letra sea distinta que toda la lista y obviamente es distinta. Una sola letra nunca será igual a una lista de letras.

Lo que tendrías que hacer sería algo como esto:

```
    palabra = "hola que tal"
    lista = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
        for letra in palabra:
            if letra not in lista:
                print( letra)
```

Por cada letra de la palabra, si la letra no está en la lista, la imprimes. Con lo que imprimiría solo los caracteres que no están en la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias,  una resolución sencilla.